# phpunit mock does not have default methods, mocking SUT does work

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to test a Symfony Entity 'RoiCalc' and phpunit's mocking framework is not working as expected.

Example 1:

I want to test that a calculation function in a controller calls certain entity getters exactly twice:

```
$subject = new RoiCalcController();

$snippets = array(
...some data...
);

$entityMock = $this->getMock( 'RoiCalc' );

$entityMock->expects( $this->exactly( 2 ) )->method( 'getFeedCost' );

$subject->doResultCalculation( $entityMock, $snippets );
```

In this example I get an error message

```
Call to undefined method Mock_RoiCalc_6dec5a53::getHerdSize()
```

I expected that $this->getMock( 'RoiCalc' ); would mock all methods of the class, at least the public ones? getHerdSize is a public function

Example 2:

I want to check that a method setDefault in my entity sets the correct values from an array:

```
$snippets = array(
    'roi_early_season_milk_production_day' => 2,
    'roi_typical_nvo_cows_9_default' => 3,
    'roi_typical_nvo_cows_21_default' => 4,
    'roi_value_ms_default' => 5,
    'roi_cost_of_feed' => 6,
    'roi_extra_feed_cow_day' => 7,
    'roi_incremental_value_heifer_default' => 8,
    'roi_dib_synch_treatment_cost_default' => 9,
    'roi_reduction_nvo_next_year_9' => 10,
    'roi_reduction_nvo_next_year_21' => 11
);

$subject = $this->getMockBuilder( 'RoiCalc' )
    ->setMethods('setTreatmentOptionId')
    ->getMock();

$subject->expects( $this->once )->method( 'setTreatmentOptionId' )->with ( $this->equalsTo( 1 ) );

$subject->setDefaults( $snippets );
```

In this case I get an error

```
Call to undefined method Mock_RoiCalc_f857be9e::setDefaults()
```

I expected that for this partial mock, all functions would come original from my class except setTreatmentOptionId

This behaviour happens both with PHPUnit 3.8.27 and 4.0.20

Answer (score 0):

As I have used a namespace for the test classes, it seems I have to use the full name for the entity, in my case:

```
$subject = $this->getMockBuilder( '\BundleGroup\BundleName\Entity\RoiCalc' )
```

or

```
$mock = $this->getMock( '\BundleGroup\BundleName\Entity\RoiCalc' )
```